# is it improper integrals?

Tags: integration

I am trying to integrate the function

$f(x)=\int_2^3\frac{1}{(x+1)(\sqrt{(3-x)(x-2)}}  dx$

I got the result, but I was wondering, can we consider this integral as an improper integral?
because $\sqrt{(3-x)(x-2)}$ and the interval $[2,3]$.

Comment: Yes it is, since formally it is $$\lim_{\epsilon_1\to2}\lim_{\epsilon_2\to3}\int_{\epsilon_1}^{\epsilon_2}\frac{dx}{(x+1)\sqrt{(x-2)(x-3)}},$$ and any method you used implicitly assumes this.

Comment: Thank you so much.

Answer (score 2):

Yes of course this is an improper integral, then observe that as $x\to 2^+$

$$\frac{1}{(x+1)(\sqrt{(3-x)(-2+x)}} \sim \frac{1}{3\sqrt{x-2}}$$

and as $x\to 3^-$

$$\frac{1}{(x+1)(\sqrt{(3-x)(-2+x)}} \sim \frac{1}{4\sqrt{3-x}}$$

and therefore the integral converges by limit comparison test.

Answer (score 1):

There is no problem since, by Taylor,
$$\frac{1}{(x+1)\sqrt{(3-x) (x-2)} }=\frac{1}{3 \sqrt{x-2}}+\frac{\sqrt{x-2}}{18}+O\left((x-2)^{3/2}\right)$$
Just do the same for the upper bound.

Answer (score 1):

$$I=\int_{a}^{b} \frac{dx}{(x-a)^{\alpha}}$$  is improper but convergenr if $\alpha <1$  Your integral is improper but convergent as $\alpha=1/2$, for both the singularities at $x=2,3.$ Eventually, your integral will be finite.

**Edit for OP**
$$I=\frac{1}{1-\alpha} (x-a)^{1-\alpha}|_{a}^{b}=\frac{(b-a)^{1-\alpha}}{1-\alpha} -\frac{(a-a)^{1-\alpha}}{1-\alpha}=\frac{(b-a)^{1-\alpha}}{1-\alpha}-0 ~~~~\text{(finite)},$$ if $\alpha <1$.

Comment: Could you please explain why it is convergence  when $\alpha =1/2$? Thank you so much.

Comment: You my see my edit above in the answer.

Comment: Thank you so much.